# requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'updateCell encountered when generating checkbox

Tags: c#

I'm trying to generate a checkbox from C#.net using google sheets API but I'm encountering the oneof field kind is already set error. I tried combining extendedValue and DataValidation. Please see code snippet below:

```
            ConditionValue conditionValueTrue = new ConditionValue();
            conditionValueTrue.UserEnteredValue = "TRUE";

            ConditionValue conditionValueFalse = new ConditionValue();
            conditionValueFalse.UserEnteredValue = "FALSE";

            ConditionValue[] validValues = { conditionValueTrue, conditionValueFalse };

            BooleanCondition bc = new BooleanCondition();
            bc.Type = "BOOLEAN"; 
            bc.Values = validValues;

            DataValidationRule dataValidationRule = new DataValidationRule();
            dataValidationRule.Condition = bc;
            dataValidationRule.ShowCustomUi = true;

            GridRange validationRange = new GridRange();
            validationRange.StartColumnIndex = 7;
            validationRange.EndColumnIndex = 7;
            validationRange.SheetId = 0;

            SetDataValidationRequest setDataValidationRequest = new SetDataValidationRequest();
            setDataValidationRequest.Rule = dataValidationRule;
            setDataValidationRequest.Range = validationRange;

            ExtendedValue extendedValue = new ExtendedValue();
            extendedValue.BoolValue = true;

            BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest busr = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
            busr.Requests = new List<Request>();
            Request r = new Request();
            busr.Requests.Add(r);
            r.UpdateCells = new UpdateCellsRequest();
            r.SetDataValidation = setDataValidationRequest;

            var gc = new GridCoordinate();
            gc.ColumnIndex = 7;
            gc.RowIndex = row;
            gc.SheetId = 0;

            r.UpdateCells.Start = gc;
            r.UpdateCells.Fields = "*";
            r.UpdateCells.Rows = new List<RowData>();

            var rd = new RowData();
            r.UpdateCells.Rows.Add(rd);
            rd.Values = new List<CellData>();
            var cd = new CellData();
            cd.UserEnteredValue = extendedValue;
            rd.Values.Add(cd);

            SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest bur = _sheetsService.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(busr, SpreadsheetId);
            bur.Execute();
```